# Simplify this expression fully

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

How would i simplify fully the following expression?

$\dfrac{{\sqrt 2}({x^3})}{\sqrt{\frac {32}{x^2}}}$

So far i have got this

$\dfrac{{\sqrt 2}{x^3}}{{\frac{\sqrt 32}{\sqrt x^2}}}$ = $\dfrac{{\sqrt 2}{x^3}}{{\frac{4\sqrt 2}{x}}}$

Am not quite sure if this is correct however, could someone help explain how i would simplify this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in the OP.  Recall that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|\ne x$ when $x<0$.  To simplify, we can write

$$\frac{\sqrt 2 x^3}{\sqrt{\frac{32}x}}=\frac{\sqrt 2 x^3}{\frac{4\sqrt 2}{|x|}}=\frac{x^3|x|}{4}$$

Comment: Am not quite sure what |x| is supposed to mean?

Comment: That is the absolute value sign.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a universal notion of when an expression is “fully simplified,” but you generally want to have a simple fraction (not a complex one, where numerator or denominator are themselves functions).  In this expression I would also try to combine all the square roots into a single radical, and put that radical in the numerator.

First, make the fraction simple:
$$
    \frac{\sqrt{2} x^3}{\sqrt{32/x^2}}
   = \frac{\sqrt{2} x^3}{\sqrt{32}/\sqrt{x^2}}
   = \frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{x^2} x^3}{\sqrt{32}}
$$
You are probably expected to simplify $\sqrt{x^2} = x$, although this is only true when $x\geq0$.  You might want to ask your teacher if you are supposed to assume $x$ is positive.

Combining the $\sqrt{2}$ in the numerator with $\sqrt{32}$ in the denominator gives
$$
    \frac{x^4}{\sqrt{16}} = \frac{x^4}{4}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$

The simplified expression would be $\frac{x^3|x|}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

It is correct so far, continue by multiplying the reciprocal of the fraction and simplifying the answer.

x^4/4 if x is positive and - x^4/4 if x is negative

Comment: Wrong, because $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Answer (score -1):

$\frac{\sqrt{2}x^3}{\sqrt{\frac{32}{x^2}}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}x^3}{\frac{\sqrt{32}}{\sqrt{x^2}}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}x^3}{\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{x}} = \frac{x^3}{\frac{4}{x}} = \frac{x^4}{4}$

Comment: Wrong, because $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.